# Plot line is hiding behind trend in highcharts and movement of plotline is become very hindrance when loaded with very large data sets

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi all I am using high stock to visualise my data. In that plot line is hiding behind the trend.is there is any way to show the plot line above the trend. and also movement of plot line become hindrance when the chart is loaded with large data sets.
[image]

I have attached image for reference. Here plot line is hiding behind the trend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `zIndex` option of plotLines to solve this problem.

```
yAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
                color: '#FF0000',
                width: 2,
                value: 80,
                zIndex: 5
        }]
}
```

You can see the live example in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XmaN6/1/).

Comment: Thanks it works fine..whether plot line movement is dependent on data set? Coz for smaller data sets it moves smoothly  but for larger data sets, it hindrance while moving

Comment: Moving speed is not about Highcharts. Since rendering large datasets are getting more time, movements on these datasets will be a bit slower than normal.

Comment: is there is any way to improve the moving speed?

Comment: You can use a "range selector" in your chart like in this example: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/areasplinerange . By doing so, only selected range of data will be visible and moving speed will be normal.

Comment: As an addition to previous comment, you can also try using Highcharts boost.js module. Here you can find information about this module: http://www.highcharts.com/news/175-highcharts-performance-boost